# How to change color of name and time next to bubble in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am sorry but it is basic question.
Though I read reference, I didn't get below question.

I want to change the color of name and time next to bubble, how can I change them ? In the picture, I want to change the color of "Mike" and "12:28"
I think there is property in the class.

[image]

Best Regards,

Comment: How did you manage to put the name and time there? If you used a custom label, then just update their values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

To change the text colour inside bubble:

```
cell.bubbleView.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I want to change the color of "Mike" and "12:28" next to bubble.

Comment: Yes, try with first line in my post. Second one is just for your information :)!

Comment: I tried with first line in your post, but it changed inside black color of "Ggggggggggggggggggggggg"

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cellForItemAtIndexPath of collection View

for time

> cell.cellBottomLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:246.0 / 255.0
>   green:187.0 / 255.0 blue: 45.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];